# Plotly: How can I delimiter (with braces ) several intervals on the y-axis

Tags: plotly, heatmap

I'm trying to add annotation to y axis based on different interval of y value and make a delimiter with braces or parentheses.

[This is what I have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbZhz.png)

In the y-axis I put IDs of different objects and make annotations ('Campo', 'Grupo' o 'Cumulo') to show in which subcategory each ID belongs. But I want to delimiter with parentheses or braces each subgroup.

For example, the three first IDs belongs to the subgroup "Campo". How can I delimiter it?

My code:

```
y_annotation = ['Campo','Grupo','Cumulo']

intervals = {'Campo':[0,len(id_campo)-1],
             'Grupo':[len(id_campo), len(id_campo)+len(id_grupo)-1],
             'Cumulo':[len(id_campo)+len(id_grupo),len(id_campo)+len(id_grupo)+ len(id_cumulo)-1]}

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
        z=dff['Color'],
        x=dff['lbt'],
        y=dff['y'],
         zmax=1 , zmin=0, 
        hovertemplate='lbt:%{x}<br>ID:%{y}<br>Index g-r:%{z}',
        showlegend=False,
        name='',
        colorscale=[[0, 'darkblue'],    
                [0.3, "blue"],
                [0.6, "white"],
                [0.8, "red"],
                [1, "darkred"],
                ],        
        colorbar=dict(
        len= 1.1,
        x=1, y=0.5,   
        title="g-r",
        titleside="top",
        tickmode="array",
        tickvals=[0,0.3,0.6,0.8,1 ],
        ticktext=['0',"0.3","0.6", "0.8",'1'],
        ticks="outside"
    )))
                                 
    

fig.update_xaxes(autorange="reversed",        
    )
fig.update_layout(
   
        xaxis=dict(
        title_text="Lbt[Gyrs]",
        #ticktext=["0", "2", "4", "6"],
        tickvals=np.array([0,2,4,6,8,10,12]),
        titlefont=dict(size=15),
             ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title_text="IDs",
        ticktext=dff['ID'].unique(),
        tickvals=np.arange(0,len(dff['ID'].unique()),1),
        
        tickmode="array",
        titlefont=dict(size=15),
             ),
))

# make room for annotations
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=150))

for k in intervals.keys():
    fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color="green",size=14),
                            #x=x_loc,
                            x=-0.28,
                            y=(intervals[k][0]+intervals[k][1])/2,
                            showarrow=False,
                            text="<i>"+k+"</i>",
                            textangle=0,
                            xref="paper",
                            yref="y"
                           ))
```

How can I do that?

Comment: There is no special means available at this time, so you will have to devise your own means in the string annotations you are creating. For example, you can put `[` before the beginning ID and  `]` after the last ID.